# I hardwired a wall lamp (with its own on-board knob switch), to a wall switch elsewhere. When turned on, spark and pop

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

We received these very generic no-brand wall lamps. They came with a plug, and simple instructions to cut the plug and hard wire if desired.

We wired them from a wall switch, but that part is likely irrelevant. Desire is for switch capabilities on the lamp AND on the wall.

We wired it in two nuts: [incoming-black / knob-black / bulb-white] and [incoming-white / knob-white / bulb-black].

Turned on the circuit, turned the wall switch on, turned the knob on, and it worked fine. High-five! Turned the lamp knob off to test, and it sparked & died.

See attached for wired in the back of lamp. What did I miss?

[image: back of light]

Comment: From your description, it seems like you put the switch in parallel with the light, not series. Please describe what we are looking at. Is that the knob switch on the right? And the wires on the left go to the bulb?

Comment: You have the switch labeled as L & N if you connected it this way in 1 direction the switch is open so nothing would happen but when the switch is flipped it is a direct short. I guess it turned off the light but not the way you desired the switch may be good but could be toast.

Comment: You didn't know anything about how to wire lamps, and you wired one anyway, and it didn't work. I'm not really sure why this is a surprise.  It sounds like your question is "tell me all the stuff to cover all the learning I didn't do", and aside from being *too broad for our format*, it's also kinda contrary to SE's credo that you should make best effort to research first, and open a question only when you reach impasse.

Comment: What @Harper said, and when you say you "hard-wired" the lamp, what do you mean exactly? You "wired it to a wall switch"... so you took the cover plate off (or drilled a hole through it) and fed wires from a switch box directly to a lamp?

Comment: And what size wire was used on what size circuit?

Comment: Could you provide a photo of the wiring at the box where you tried to hard wire. Was it an actual switch or was it a switched receptacle?

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts, all! We ended up wiring it by bypassing the knob altogether. We capped each of the knob's wires independently, and wired the switch/wall straight to the bulb. There were TWO of these lights, and the other one (wired the same as this one) worked fine, so something was up with the knob as-purchased.
Addressing your questions:
Yes, the knob switch is the pair of wires on the right.
The "L" and "N" were factory labels.
This is a rebuilt wall, so it is a new switch and box.
12-gauge wire, on 20-amp circuit.
Thanks, all! Bypassing the on-board knobs is working fine.